# Making a 2D torus interconnect with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to make a 2D dimensional torus interconnect using `networkx` library in python. I have achieved this using the following code in matlab.

```
%..points for grid....%
S=4;  % Side length of grid
N=S^2;    % Number of nodes in network

v1=[1:S];
[c1 c2]=meshgrid(v1,v1);

points(:,1)=2*c1(:);
points(:,2)=2*c2(:);
%...end of points for grid...%

D=squareform(pdist(points));   % Caluclate distances between points
D1=D+eye(N);

Dbin=D<RI;                      % Deciding conflicting nodes

%......Extra edges for torus.....%
for i=1:S
    Dbin(i,i+(S-1)*S)=1;
    Dbin(i+(S-1)*S,i)=1;

    Dbin(S*i,S*(i-1)+1)=1;
    Dbin(S*(i-1)+1,S*i)=1;
end
%......Extra edges for torus.....%
```

I can do something similar in python using numpy, but I want to use `networkx` library. I don't know how to do this.

Edit:

I've created a square lattice using the following code. But have to figure out how to connect the peripheral edges as shown in the figure below.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.grid_graph(dim = [4,4])
```

Is there a way to generalize this to an nxn grid with peripheral connections.

This is how the graph looks like. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make that diagram in networkx, however I created a similar diagram using latex and tikz. Seems a little inefficient but got the job done.
[image: Acceptable Quality Diagram]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,scopes,quotes,bending,calc,intersections}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw,minimum width=1em,minimum height=1em,align=center,fill=blue!30},
    arrow/.style={->},
    line/.style={-}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',node distance=0.5cm]
    % Creating rows of blocks
    {[start chain]
        \node[on chain] (s0) {};
        \node[on chain] (s1) {};
        \node[on chain] (s2) {};
        \node[on chain] (s3) {};
        \node[on chain] (s4) {};
    }
    {[start chain]
        \node[block,on chain, below = 0.15 cm of s0] (A0) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (A1) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (A2) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (A3) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (A4) {};
    }
    {[start chain]
        \node[block,on chain, below = of A0] (B0) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (B1) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (B2) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (B3) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (B4) {};
    }
    {[start chain]
        \node[block,on chain, below = of B0] (C0) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (C1) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (C2) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (C3) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (C4) {};
    }
    {[start chain]
        \node[block,on chain, below = of C0] (D0) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (D1) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (D2) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (D3) {};
        \node[block,on chain, join =by {line}] (D4) {};
    }

    % Drawing vertical lines
    \draw (A0) -- (B0) -- (C0) -- (D0); % -- (E0);
    \draw (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1) -- (D1); % -- (E1);
    \draw (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2); % -- (E2);
    \draw (A3) -- (B3) -- (C3) -- (D3); % -- (E3);
    \draw (A4) -- (B4) -- (C4) -- (D4); % -- (E4);
    % Drawing loop backs horizontal
    \draw (A0.west) -- ($(A0.west) - (0.15, 0)$);
    \draw ($(A0.west) - (0.15, 0)$) -- ($(A0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(A0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(A0.west) +(4,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(A0.west) +(4,0.5)$) |- (A4.east);
    % \draw (A0.north) |- (s2.north east) -| (A4.north);
    % B row
    \draw (B0.west) -- ($(B0.west) - (0.15, 0)$);
    \draw ($(B0.west) - (0.15, 0)$) -- ($(B0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(B0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(B0.west) +(4,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(B0.west) +(4,0.5)$) |- (B4.east);
    % C row
    \draw (C0.west) -- ($(C0.west) - (0.15, 0)$);
    \draw ($(C0.west) - (0.15, 0)$) -- ($(C0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(C0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(C0.west) +(4,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(C0.west) +(4,0.5)$) |- (C4.east);
    % D row
    \draw (D0.west) -- ($(D0.west) - (0.15, 0)$);
    \draw ($(D0.west) - (0.15, 0)$) -- ($(D0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(D0.west) - (0.15, 0)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(D0.west) +(4,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(D0.west) +(4,0.5)$) |- (D4.east);

    % Vertical Loopbacks

    % 0 column
    \draw (A0.north) -- ($(A0.north) + (0.0, 0.15)$);
    \draw ($(A0.north) + (0, 0.15)$) -- ($(A0.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$);
    \draw ($(A0.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(D0.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$);
    \draw ($(D0.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$) -| (D0.south);
    % 1 column
    \draw (A1.north) -- ($(A1.north) + (0.0, 0.15)$);
    \draw ($(A1.north) + (0, 0.15)$) -- ($(A1.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$);
    \draw ($(A1.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(D1.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$);
    \draw ($(D1.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$) -| (D1.south);
    % 2 column
    \draw (A2.north) -- ($(A2.north) + (0.0, 0.15)$);
    \draw ($(A2.north) + (0, 0.15)$) -- ($(A2.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$);
    \draw ($(A2.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(D2.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$);
    \draw ($(D2.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$) -| (D2.south);

    % 3 column
    \draw (A3.north) -- ($(A3.north) + (0.0, 0.15)$);
    \draw ($(A3.north) + (0, 0.15)$) -- ($(A3.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$);
    \draw ($(A3.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(D3.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$);
    \draw ($(D3.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$) -| (D3.south);

    % 4 column
    \draw (A4.north) -- ($(A4.north) + (0.0, 0.15)$);
    \draw ($(A4.north) + (0, 0.15)$) -- ($(A4.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$);
    \draw ($(A4.north) + (0, 0.15)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(D4.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$);
    \draw ($(D4.north) +(-0.5,-0.65)$) -| (D4.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```